# div height:100% and display:flex not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Bootstrap 3.0 is also used. I want boxes to be of same height & more link on right box is at right position but box is ending before more link.

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/je6qtkLn/1/)

HTML

```
<div class="container body-content">
    <div class="row categoryrow">
        <div class="col-md-6 categoryblock">
            <div class="category">
                <div>
                    India faces acute shortage of cancer specialists, only one doctor available for every 2,500 patients
                    India faces acute shortage of cancer specialists, only one doctor available for every 2,500 patients
                </div>
                <span class="morelink">
                    <a href="/Category/Health">More..</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 categoryblock">
            <div class="category">
                <div>
                    Sensex, Nifty slightly up in early trade
                </div>
                <span class="morelink">
                    <a href="/Category/Business">More..</a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.categoryrow {
     display: flex;
 }
 .categoryblock {
     margin-bottom: 10px;
     width: 100%;
 }
 .category {
     border-radius: 5px;
     border: 1px solid #2bbcef;
     height: 100%;
     padding: 2px;
 }
 .morelink {
     font-style: italic;
     float: right;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     position: absolute;
     margin-right: 20px;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can drastically cut down on the amount of HTML markup.

**To get each block to the same height:**

- The row that wraps the two content blocks is given `display: flex;`
- The two content blocks are given `flex: 1;` and height properties are removed.

**To get the "read more" links positioned properly:**

- The content blocks are given `position: relative;` so that the links are positioned relative to their containers and not the viewport.
- The right amount of padding is given to each content block.

Place all your content in the content block and use `<h1>` for the heading and `<p>` for the main content paragraph.

**Note:** Some browsers, such as Safari, currently only support a prefixed flex property. I have included the `-webkit` prefix in the CSS snippet below. Always place it *before* the un-prefixed property.

[Here is a good reference for browser support.](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

CSS / HTML / Demo

```css
.row {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* Prefixed for Safari */
    display: flex;
}
.content {
    -webkit-flex:1;
    /* Prefixed for Safari */
    flex:1;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #2bbcef;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px 10px 30px;
}
.more {
    font-style: italic;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Heading</h1> 
        <p>India faces acute shortage of cancer specialists, only one doctor available for every 2,500 patients India faces acute shortage of cancer specialists, only one doctor available for every 2,500 patients</p> <a class="more" href="/Category/Health">More..</a>

    </div>
    <div class="content">
         <h1>Heading</h1> 
        <p>Sensex, Nifty slightly up in early trade</p> <a class="more" href="/Category/Business">More..</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, very nice answer.But it is not yet working for me. DIV having .content class has 3 DIV's in IT first with heading,second with content and third with more link.

Comment: Simplify your markup and use `<h1>` and `<p>` ***inside*** `.content`. [Here is an updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/th2jwpsa/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, +1 for helping to remove unnecessary HTML.

Comment: @minsterManSam, This is not working in Safari browser, any IDEA?

Comment: @AK47 - [flex is only supported in Safari using a `-webkit-` prefix.](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) Use it [like this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7rcmtL7n/1/) and always put prefixed properties in front. I will update my answer :)

Comment: @minsterManSam, thanks for so quick response, but "this example" that you have provided is also not working correctly in safai.

Comment: @AK47 - What version are you using? It works fine for me (Safari Version 7.0.3 Mac OS 10.9)

Comment: @minsterManSam, it is 5.1.7 (7534.57.2). Is it outdated?

Comment: [If you look at the reference here](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex), you can see that Safari 5.1 and 6 support the old flexbox specification. We might find a workable fix though. Is your userbase going to be running such old versions of Safari? Globally they are used by less than 1% of users. Safari 5.1 and 6 are obsolete.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61654/discussion-between-ak47-and-mistermansam).

Answer (score 0):

first, you need to add position:relative; to the parent of the element with position:absolute.. in this case:

```
.category {
position: relative;
```

}

also, if you add to an element height 100%, but no height on the parents.. 100% of nothing is 0. so add 100% height (if that's what you desire) to all parents... here is your js modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/je6qtkLn/3/

Comment: But misterManSam answer is much better and accurate than mine.. so follow his solution.